# Why in the idiomatic phrase "to catch a cold" is there an article even though it's uncountable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

The word "**cold**' is a [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun), meaning that it's uncountable noun. We cannot count *cold* as we cannon count *hot*. Nevertheless, we find a usage of "to catch **a** cold" using of an article before the mass noun "cold".

What is the explanation for that?

Comment: Checking some actual usage examples would have helped you understand this. Or at least should have been added to your question. You are making the assumption that *cold* only has one meaning.

Answer (score 6):

It's not uncountable in the case where it's referring to the illness.

> I caught a cold last week.
>
> This winter I've had three colds.

Answer (score 6):

The noun *cold* has two basic meanings :

cold noun (ILLNESS) Countable

a common infection, especially in the nose and throat, that often causes a cough, a slight fever, etc.

> She caught a cold at school.

cold noun (LOW TEMPERATURE)Singular or Uncountable

cold weather or temperatures:

> Don't stand out there in the cold, come in here and get warm.
>   My feet were numb with cold.

Thus, in your example it is a countable noun.

Comment: Isn't "coldness"  the noun for the meaning "low temperature", with "cold"  the adjectival form?